Convert enum to another enum in Rust while selectively moving contained values
I have two enums like this:
enum E1 {
  A { val: SomeValue1 },
  B(SomeValue2),
  C(SomeValue3),
}

enum E2 {
  A,
  B(SomeValue2),
  C(SomeValue3),
  D,
  E
}

Here the SomeValueX types don't implement Copy or Clone.
I'm trying to write code that takes E1 as an input and does the following:

Perform some actions on the contained values. If the input is E1::A(val), it needs to take ownership of val.
Convert the input to E2

Currently I'm doing something like this:
fn example(input: E1) -> E2 {
  match input {
    E1::A(val) => { do_something_with_a(val); E2::A },
    E1::B(val) => { do_something_with_b(&val); E2::B(val) },
    E1::C(val) => { do_something_with_c(&val); E2::C(val) },
  }
}

Is there any way to clean this up and potentially split 1. and 2. into separate functions? I didn't succeed in doing it because:

If the conversion function (2) consumes the E1 value, the E1::A(val) gets lost and can't be consumed by do_something_with_a.
If the conversion function takes E1 by reference, it can't construct the E2::B and E2::C variants.

I'm open to changing the enums as needed or using macros.

This seems fairly idiomatic to me.

The do_something_with_* functions could, I suppose, always take ownership of their argument and return an E2.  That might not fit their intended semantics, however.

@cdhowie That's good to know. The real code looks differently (the enum names are much longer, the do_something_with_x functions are actually variable assignments), so I was looking to restructure it. I should probably work in a different direction.

If you really like it better as two functions, you can change the order of your operations. Do 2 before 1.
So you'll have one function that deconstructs E1 into E2 plus an optional Option<SomeValue1> as a tuple:
fn deconstruct_your2(input: E1) -> (E2, Option<SomeValue1>) {
    match input {
        E1::A(val) => (E2::A, Option::Some(val)),
        E1::B(val) => (E2::B(val), Option::None),
        E1::C(val) => (E2::C(val), Option::None),
    }
}

And then another function that only borrows E2 and consumes the Option<SomeValue1> (taking ownership of SomeValue1):
fn useInput_your1(input: &E2, input2: Option<Some1>) -> () {
    match input {
        E2::A => do_something_with_a(input2.expect("intput error: you must provide Option::Some(x) input2 in case of A")),
        E2::B(val) => do_something_with_b(val),
        E2::C(val) => do_something_with_c(val),
        _ => {}
    }
}

Then you can chain them like this:
fn example(input: E1) -> E2 {
    let (a, b) = deconstruct_your2(input);
    useInput_your1(&a, b);
    return a;
}


The .expect() doesn't look ideal, but thanks a lot for showing the solution. Accepting the answer.
